# Map array of objects into new groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, javascript-objects, v-select

I have an object with two arrays of objects being returned from an API. I need to try to map this into a new array of objects so I can group the data for the Vue `v-select` component. [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/JjYraqX)

```js
fields: {
      current: [
        {
          name: 'Date'
        },
        {
          name: 'Time'
        }
      ],
      previous: [
        {
          name: 'Birthday'
        },
        {
          name: 'Comments'
        }
      ]
    },
```

How can I map this into a new array of objects that looks like this?

```js
grouped: [
      {
        group: "Current",
      },
      {
        name: "Date"
      },
      {
        name: "Time"
      },
      {
        group: "Previous"
      },
      {
        name: "Birthday"
      },
      {
        name: "Comments"
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` to get the groups, and their values, and map them using `Array.flatMap()`. Create the group's object, and add it to an array with the group's items.

```js
const flattenGroups = fields =>
  Object.entries(fields)
    .flatMap(([group, items]) => [{ group }, ...items])

const fields = {"current":[{"name":"Date"},{"name":"Time"}],"previous":[{"name":"Birthday"},{"name":"Comments"}]}

const result = flattenGroups(fields)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I was trying to do it using `reduce` but was getting into a bit of a mix up. This is nice and succinct.

Comment: You're welcome. May you find the lost bark :)